# Work done by F (vector field) on C (curve)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, greens-theorem

Let $C$ be the rectangle, with vertices at points $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(2,0)$, $(2,1)$ and an anticlockwise orientation. Let $$F=(P(x,y),Q(x,y))$$ be a vector field with $$P=y^2+e^{x^2}+ye^{xy}$$ and $$Q=xe^{xy}$$Find the work done by **F** along **C**.

I have started by drawing up the region of the rectangle which is $0\to2$ in the $x$ direction and $0\to1$ in the $y$ direction. I then checked if the vector field **F** is conservative using $P_y = Q_x$. Calculating $P_y$ and $Q_x$ resulted $P_y \neq Q_x$ and hence the field being not conservative.

Would I be correct in applying Greens Theorem in this case?

$$\int\int_DQ_x-P_y=\int_0^2\int_0^1(e^{yx}+ye^{yx})-(2y+e^{xy}(xy+1))dydx$$

Comment: That sounds about correct if you can evaluate those double integrals easily.

Comment: @MathNewbie what other could I use to make the Integral easier? It just seems quite difficult to integrate using this method.

Comment: grdgfgr's answer provides another alternative in evaluating the line integral via stoke's theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\nabla \times F=-2 y$$

Call the surface of rectangle $S$

$$\int _ {\partial S}F \cdot dl= \int \int _ S\nabla \times F\cdot dS$$

Comment: I see you used Stokes theorem. Could you please expand a bit on your calculations? Thanks :)

Comment: Since your vector field is on $\mathbb{R}^2$, you can extend it so that $F(x,y,z) = (P(x,y,z),Q(x,y,z), 0)$ where $P(x,y,z) = P(x,y), Q(x,y,z) = Q(x,y)$. Recall that the $\mathrm{curl}(F) = \nabla \times F$, where $\nabla = (\partial_x, \partial_y, \partial_z)$ and $\times$ is the cross product.

Comment: I look at your post more closely and you had already found $-2y$ and were going to integrate it over the surface (which is correct, and what Stoke's theorem would also suggest. $\partial S$ means the boundary of $S$). Stoke's theorem is very general. Green's theorem is just the 2 Dimensional special case of Stoke's Theorem.

Comment: ah ok, I understand it now. thanks for your help!